# Google maps v3 error drawing encoded polyline

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I have one map where users can draw a polyline, encode it and then save it to a mySQL database. Then, there's another map which queries the encoded string from the DB, decodes the polyline and displays it on the map.

I'm using the `encodePath()` function from the geometry library like this:

```
    if(overlayType == 'POLYGON'){
        newPolygonOverlay = overlaysArray[0];   //only one overlay
        newPolygonPath = newPolygonOverlay.getPath();    //get the path
        newPolygonPathCoordsStr = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(newPolygonPath);    //encode it
```

this code produces a string like this:

```
    wwzhBz~|gP~mhMygvCt`cDjgiH{ohIf{fA
```

I then proceed to store this string in a mySQL DB using the *mediumtext* type.

The second map, queries the DB to get the encoded polyline string, which is exactly the same as the one I saved originally.

I then decode the string using the decode function from the geometry library and create the polyline, like this:

```
    var array = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(str);  //str contains the encoded string from the db
    var levels = decodeLevels("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");

    var Poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: array,
      levels: levels,
      strokeColor: '66FF00',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
```

My problem is that somewhere along the way, some of the polyline points get messed up and the resulting polyline is not the same as the original.

I have tried using the *blob* type in mySQL. Same result.

I have tried bypassing the DB by declaring a string variable on the second map with the encoded string. Same result.

Comment: What is the [line](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GenericMapBrowser.asp?filename=SO_Polyline_encoded.xml) supposed to look like?

Comment: Does the line look correct if you plug it in here? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility

Comment: The original line looks correct, but the line queried from the DB doesn't. I tested several lines and found out that the "\b"'s are not getting stored on the DB, there's my problem. The solution seems to be to escape it like "\\b". What other characters would need escaping?

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> The problem was the backslash characters being interpreted (and removed) by javascript. So by the time the encoded string reached the DB, it no longer contained backslashes, making the polyline a completely different polyline. I tried replacing single backslashes with double backslashes: "\" -> "\", but I was having trouble with this until I did the replace over the encode function; like this:

```
newRoutePathCoordsStr = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(newRoutePath).replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
```